# FileNotFound Exception Error

Tags: java

Hello everyone I am new to java and I am having some trouble as to why I am getting a file not found exception. I'm simply trying to get the user to open a file using jfilechooser and then print the ONE LINE text into a option pane message. Any ideas as to what is wrong/what needs to be fixed? Thanks

```
package synchro;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SynchroTest {
     public static void main(String[] args){
     JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
          File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());

      try{
      Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(selectedFile.getName()));
      while(input.hasNext()){
      String line = input.nextLine();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Input sentence:\n" + line);
      }

      }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
          System.out.println("File Not Found");
      }
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: why dont you just use - `Scanner input = new Scanner(selectedFile);`

Comment: what was that error?

Comment: No suitable constructor found for File(file). The scanner is looking for the name of the file. If I just put selectedFile it runs the fileChooser.getSelectedFile(); command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are going around in loops.

`File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();` gives you a [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object for the file that was clicked on.

Simply using `Scanner input = new Scanner(selectedFile);` will allow you to parse the file.

```
while( input.hasNext() ) {
    String line = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);
}
```